# what is the command to synchronize samba4 ADC -> PDC

Tags: ubuntu, samba, samba4, zentyal-linux

I have another question on here that is almost exactly the same, but it had a lot more details and kind of went off track (and I never got my answer).  So I'm trying again.

I know that this command works. When sent FROM my Samba4 ADC, the following command successfully replicates PDC -> ADC

```
sudo net rpc share migrate files sysvol \
    -k --destination=ADCserverName.companyname.local \
    -S PDCserverName.companyname.local --acls \
    -U "companyname\\AdminAccountName"
```

What would the command be to replicate ADC -> PDC?  Do I simply reverse the `--destination` and `-S`?